# Add separate icons on home screen

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to add multiple icons with shortcuts on home screen. For example i would like to add two icons with specific shortcuts:

1. First icon-> Open Google.com in Google Chrome
2. Second icon -> Open YoutubeApp

I don't want to use shortcuts with one default icon, like in this example: [enter link description here](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/android/create-shortcuts-android-application-show-menu-long-press-app-icon/)

I would like to generate separately icon for specific shortcut.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your example says, there are 3 types of shortcuts:

> Static shortcuts:- Context doesn’t change

> Dynamic Shortcuts:- Context constantly changes

> Pinned Shortcuts:- Context is defined by the user

If you want those shortcuts to be an icon on your home screen, you should use pinned shortcuts.

When you execute the code below, you will add a Pinned Shortcut that opens google.com.

```
val shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager::class.java)
if (shortcutManager!!.isRequestPinShortcutSupported) {
    val pinShortcutInfo = ShortcutInfo.Builder(applicationContext, "shortcut_to_google")
        .setShortLabel("open Google.com")
        .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(applicationContext, R.drawable.example_icon))
        .setLongLabel("This is a pinned shortcut.")
        .setIntent(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://google.com/")))
        .build()
    val pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent = shortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent(pinShortcutInfo)
    val successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 0, pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent, 0)
    shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(pinShortcutInfo, successCallback.intentSender)
}
```

Comment: Great, thank  you :) Could you tell me how can i avoid possible duplicating icons?

Comment: @Derkas pass a different icon to ``setIcon``!